# Submodules of the tensor product of a representation and its dual

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a simple, finite-dimensional, complex Lie algebra and let $V$ be an irreducible nontrivial representation. Is it true that $V \otimes V^*$ always contains copies of $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathfrak{g}$?

Comment: Yes.$\!\!\!\!\!$

Comment: @TravisWillse How can I see this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

**Hint** The canonical pairing $$\operatorname{tr} : V \otimes V^* \to \Bbb C$$ is nonzero, so it is a surjection.

> It determines a ($\mathfrak{g}$-module) decomposition $$V \otimes V^* = \operatorname{id}_V \Bbb C \oplus \ker \operatorname{tr}$$ into trace and tracefree parts.

**Hint** On the other hand, as a (nontrivial) representation of $\mathfrak g$ we may view it as a (nonzero) homomorphism $$\mathfrak{g} \to \mathfrak{gl}(V) \cong V \otimes V^* .$$

> Since $\mathfrak{g}$ is simple, this homomorphism must be injective.

**Remark** In a few cases these are the only irreducible subrepresentations. If $\mathfrak{g}$ is $\mathfrak{sl}(n + 1, \Bbb C)$ and $V$ is the standard representation $V := \Bbb C^n$, the tensor product $V \otimes V^*$ decomposes into trace and tracefree parts, and in this case the latter is just adjoint representation $\mathfrak{sl}(n, \Bbb C) = \mathfrak{sl}(V)$:
$$V \otimes V^* \cong \mathfrak{gl}(V) \cong \Bbb C \oplus \mathfrak{sl}(V) .$$